# MongoDB Service not started with WAMP

Tags: php, mongodb, installation, wamp

I am a newbie to MongoDB and followed [this](http://www.pronique.com/blog/installing-mongodb-on-windows-the-wamp-way) for installation purpose. In my `phpinfo`, I can see `mongodb` under `Apache Environment`, `Environment` and `PHP Variables`. When I try starting MongoDB service it shows the error as in screensshot

[image: Service not started]

Also I can not see it installed like below

[image: MongoDB Installed]

My `DLL` file is `php_mongo-1.5.5-5.4-vc9-x86_64` and MongoDB is installed from [here](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads)

```
PHP Version    5.4.3
Compiler       MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture   x86
System Type    64 bit
```

Could someone please guide me on how to install MongoDB with PHP

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you did something wrong when installing the mongod service. Review all those steps. Also look in the Windows Event Log, there may be some useful error messages in there.

Comment: You are conflating two different services here: the first screenshot is the MongoDB server (via Windows Services list) and the second is the `Mongo` PHP extension (aka "client driver") that lets PHP applications connect to MongoDB. To troubleshoot the error with the MongoDB server, I would have a look in the log file path you used when you created the service definition (eg. `c:\wamp\mongodb\mongodb-win32…2.x.x\logs\mongodb.log` if you followed the tutorial you linked). That should have a more specific error.

Comment: It's not clear if you have an error with the PHP driver; you said you can see MongoDB in `phpinfo()` but don't have a `mongo` section listed in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responding. I resolved it my `uninstalling` the MongoDB services and then again installing a relevant version.

The source code issue was of previous `MongoDB` version and not the latest one, and the folder containing the old version was deleted somehow, thus throwing an exception for `source path not found`.

Also, the `DLL` file that worked was `php_mongo-1.5.5-5.4-vc9.dll` downloaded from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html) for below configuration

```
PHP Version    5.4.3
Compiler       MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture   x86
System Type    64 bit
```

Hope it helps someone.